# Regarding category theory, if two monoids have the same number of arrows, can they represent different categories?

Tags: category-theory, monoid

For example, consider a pair of monoids of degree three. That is, in each monoid there are three arrows $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$, all of which are reflexive. Would it make sense to identify the composition of $a_1$ with $a_2$ with only *one* of the arrows? If so, then there could be several distinct monoids of degree three, for example one with $a_1 *a_2$=$a_3$ and another with $a_1*a_2=a_1$ but $a_1*a_2\ne a_3$, etc.. On the other hand, if the composition of $a_1$ with $a_2$ is always identified with all three arrows then all monoids with degree three would represent the same category.

So my question is about definitions - what defines a category, the specific arrows resulting from composition or the pairs of elements that are connected by composition of arrows?

Comment: > *what defines a category, the specific arrows resulting from composition or the pairs of elements that are connected by composition of arrows?* I'd say both. The same arrows with a different composition law yield a different category; the same composition law, but more/less constraint on which arrows you compose, also yield a different category.

Comment: If you want a precise answer regarding your question on monoids, you have to state it more clearly: whats the "degree" of a monoid? Its cardinality? What's a "reflexive" element of a monoid? Certainly, two monoids with different cardinalities can't be isomorphic, nor they can be isomorphic if they have different operations (say, different Cayley tables)

Comment: Degree is the number of arrows. Reflexive means an arrow going from the one element back to itself. So the question remains, can there be two monoids, both with three arrows, that represent different categories? I think either there can be or there cannot be.

Comment: I don't understand: in a monoid regarded as a category, all arrows are endomorphisms. Also, "degree" is cardinality, because the monoid has exactly as many elements as there are arrows in its correspondent category.

Comment: > *can there be two monoids, both with three arrows, that represent different categories?* [There are exactly seven monoid structures you can put on a three-element set](http://oeis.org/A058129).

Comment: > *I think either there can be or there cannot be.* So you don't believe in the law of excluded middle? :-)

Comment: Thanks for your "yes"

Comment: > *OK would it help if I edited my question and replaced the word "arrow" with "endomorphisom" and the word "degree" with "cardinatlity"? Would that make it a well-posed question?* The problem is not (only) that the question is not well-posed. You seem very confused on how a monoid can be regarded as a category, or rather this question would look quite obvious to answer. Now, [help me to help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk31L6H8eNQ): is everything solved now? Do you have more perplexities?

Comment: All good thanks